# Is it possible to place syncframework tracking tables on a different db?

Tags: database, microsoft-sync-framework

Might seem like a strange question but we have a situation where we can't add tables to the local db. So I was wondering, if it's possible to place the tracking table on a different db.

```
maindb:dbo.staff

main2db:dbostaff_tracking
```

I don't think you can and haven't found anything to indicate it but hey lets make use of shared knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can script out the provisioning of the sync objects. you can manually alter the scripts to change the db for the change tracking tables but you will have to alter the triggers and the other stored procedures to do cross-db queries as well.

Comment: thanks, once I've got the syncframework running on the dev I'll look into amending scripts - my gut feeling is it could be a bit messy tho.